# Node.js with Angular - CORS error when i send request

Tags: node.js, angular

I have problem with my node.js API. I have API running on port 3000, and angular frontend with port 4200.

When i send request from angular to API, i have error with CORS. I tried three different solution, but still not working.

1. First solution is install cors package, and add to code

> app.use(cors());

2. Second solution is add code below:

> ```
>  app.use((req, res, next) => {
>    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
>    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
>    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
>    next();
> })
> ```

3. Last solution is add code below, with frontend url:

> ```
> app.use(cors({
>   origin: 'http://frontend.com:4200'
> }));
> ```

None of the above worked, i.e. I still get an error with CORS all the time. When i send request from Postman, all works fine.

My actual code:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const carRoutes = require('./routes/car');
const sequelize = require('./util/db');
const cors = require('cors');

sequelize.sync().catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

app.use(carRoutes);
app.listen(3001);
```

Error message:

> A request to a resource of another origin has been blocked: the "Same
>   Origin Policy" policy does not allow remote resources to be loaded
>   from "http://localhost:3000/car" (failed CORS request).

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo I add error message to my post

Comment: Does it have anything to do with the fact that in your example your backend server is listening on 3001 but you are using 3000?

Comment: Have you tried `app.use(cors({ origin: true }))` ?

Comment: @pawelC,  did it fix.. was the solution working for u?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes CORS is more than just Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Try the following:

```
// Set up CORS
app.use(cors({
    origin: true, // "true" will copy the domain of the request back
                  // to the reply. If you need more control than this
                  // use a function.

    credentials: true, // This MUST be "true" if your endpoint is
                       // authenticated via either a session cookie
                       // or Authorization header. Otherwise the
                       // browser will block the response.

    methods: 'POST,GET,PUT,OPTIONS,DELETE' // Make sure you're not blocking
                                           // pre-flight OPTIONS requests
}));
```

You may also play around with `allowedHeaders`, `exposedHeaders` etc. Setting `maxAge` will reduce the number of pre-flight requests - it doesn't really fix cors issues but will reduce network traffic.

> Note on `origin: true`. If your endpoint requires credentials then the browser will not respect the `*` pattern. The Access-Control-Allow-Origin header **must** match the url of the request (including weather it's http or https). Fortunately the `cors` middleware will do this automatically for you if you set `origin` to `true`

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution is to implement a proxy which will redirect your API call to localhost:300. 
Add a new file called `proxy.config.json` add the following json configuration in it.

```
{
    "/car/*": {
        "target": "http://localhost:3000", 
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

after this, you need to update your `package.json` update your `Scripts` section with the following code: `"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json",`. Do the above in your use `npm start` otherwise, you can just run `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json` at the command line without updating your `package.json`, but you will have to remember to run it each time.

Comment: Missing the `changeOrigin: true` flag.

Comment: what is "car" here?

Comment: this means baseurl/car/*?