# How to call microservice (built in express js) from angular app which is already calling sails js backend?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, sails.js, microservices

I already have an application with angular front end and sails js backend. But due to some reason I moved some backend functions in seperate express project like micro-service. But Now I want to call those functions. Kindly tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this:

1. **CORS**

   Your microservice should enable cors so that the browser doesn't block its responses. In Express this can be as simple as:

   ```
   const cors = require('cors');

   app.use(cors());
   ```

   Depending on weather the endpoint requires credentials (login) you may have to set a few options for cors:

   ```
    app.use(cors({
        credentials: true,
        origin: true,
        methods: 'POST,GET,PUT,OPTIONS,DELETE'
    }));
   ```

   see my answer to this other question: [Node.js with Angular - CORS error when i send request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56798251/node-js-with-angular-cors-error-when-i-send-request/57308205#57308205)

   Check out the documentation of the `cors` middleware for configuration options: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors
2. **Application Gateway**

   You can also run all your microservices behind a reverse proxy such as [Nginx](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) or [Apache2](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html) or [HAproxy](http://www.haproxy.org/). This strategy is what makes Amazon work before 2014 (before browsers implemented CORS).

   Here's a simple example of an Nginx configuration for proxying your microservice:

   ```
   # The ^~ operator matches all urls that begins with the following string:

   location ^~ /some/microservice {
     proxy_pass http://some.microservice.myapp.com;
   }
   ```

   A reverse proxy that maps multiple microservices to url paths on a single domain name is often called an Application Gateway in the industry. Application Gateways also provide additional benefits such as load-balancing, firewalling the internal servers form the internet etc. But for our purposes the main reason to use it is to allow microservices to be served form the same domain as your front-end code which means making requests to microservices does not trigger cross-origin policy.

Either way, to request data from your microservices you'd just make an ajax request. Either via old-school `XMLHttpRequest` or the more modern [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) API:

```
// Assuming you've configured CORS correctly on your server:
fetch('https://some.microservice.myapp.com/getdata')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  });

// Assuming you are using an application gateway:
fetch('https://myapp.com/some/microservice/getdata')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  });
```

Comment: Can you see the request/response in the network tab in the browser?

Comment: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/dashboard/reports. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).
Getting this error