# CORS Policy Error When Authorizing Shopify Integration with Angular(Frontend) and Node.js(Backend)

Tags: node.js, angular, cors, shopify-app

I am encountering a CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) policy issue while trying to authorize a Shopify integration with Backend(Nodejs). Here's the specific error message I'm facing:

**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://contosostore.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/authorize?client_id=36eb**********02&scope=write_customers%2Cwrite_products%2Cwrite_orders&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fapi%2Fshopify%2Fauth%2Fcallback&state=980648035530556&grant_options%5B%5D=' (redirected from 'https://localhost:3000/api/shopify/auth') from origin 'https://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource**.

Here's an overview of my setup:

Frontend: Angular
Backend: Node.js
Shopify Integration: Using the @shopify/shopify-api library

The issue arises when I click on a "Generate Token" button in my Angular frontend, which initiates the authorization process with Shopify through a request to my Node.js backend. The backend code for the authorization process is as follows:

```
async auth(_req, _res) {
  // Get Shopify object
  const shopify = await shopifyObject.getShopifyObject();

  // Authorization with Shopify
  await shopify.auth.begin({
    shop: shopify.utils.sanitizeShop('contosostore.myshopify.com', true),
    callbackPath: process.env.SHOPIFY_REDIRECT_URL,
    isOnline: false,
    rawRequest: _req,
    rawResponse: _res
  });

  console.log(shopify);

  // The shopify will call the backend(NodeJs) authCallback function automatically
}
```

The CORS config in nodejs are,

```
// Cors setup
APP.use(CORS())
APP.options('*', CORS())
```

It seems that the CORS issue is preventing my Angular frontend from making requests to Shopify's authorization endpoint. I have ensured that my Shopify app settings are correctly configured with the redirect URL

I've tried various solutions, including adding CORS headers to my Node.js backend, like in this post

[Node.js with Angular - CORS error when i send request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56798251/node-js-with-angular-cors-error-when-i-send-request)

but I'm still facing this issue. Any guidance on how to resolve this CORS policy error would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!